# JS: Обращение к элементу на странице, генерация события "Клик"

Tags: javascript, razor

Есть некоторая страница на которой мне нужно по клику на ссылку отметить чекбокс и сгенерировать событие нажатия на кнопку:

`<input type="submit" name="updatecart" id="btn_update" value="@T("Wishlist.UpdateCart")" class="button-2 update-wishlist-button" /> <!--Update Wishlist-->`

Сам скрипт выглядит так:

```
<script language="JavaScript">

    function set_check()
    {
        $('#cb_remove').prop('checked', true);
    }
    jQuery('btn_delete').click(set_check());

    let event = new Event("click");
    @*$('#btn_update').dispatchEvent(event);*@<!--в @**@ заключён комментарий, т.к. работаю с Razor Pages-->
    var pbUpdate;
    pbUpdate = document.getElementById('btn_update');
    pbUpdate.dispatchEvent("click");
</script>
```

В конечном итоге он не работает. Браузер Opera выдаёт ошибку:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispatchEvent' of null
    at wishlist:1`

Как это исправить? Что я делаю не так?

Как обратиться к элементу с целью генерации события нажатия на него ЛКМ?(Уже перекопал не мало страниц в гугле и ничего не работает =( )

Comment: (метод тыка): Попробуйте так:  `@* ( $('#btn_update').dispatchEvent(event); ) *@`P.s. в jQuery есть `.trigger('click');`

Comment: первый вариант уже пробовал, как вы можете видеть. $('') is not a function

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME оформите ответ. Вариант с триггером оказался рабочим.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поместите скрипт ниже элемента

```
<input type="submit" name="updatecart" id="btn_update" ...
```

или заверните скрипт в `$(document).ready(...`.

---

```
function set_check()
{
    $('#cb_remove').prop('checked', true);
}
jQuery('#btn_delete').click(set_check);
```

---

```
document.getElementById('btn_update').dispatchEvent(new Event("click"));
```